# How do I make text wrap in a JQuery Mobile list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

It seems that by default, text within <P> tags in a Query Mobile list item doesn't wrap, rather it is truncated at the edge of the screen with a "...".

How do I change this behavior such that it wraps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the object, you should be able to add the following in your CSS:

```
white-space: normal;
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, because higher elements set it to `white-space: no-wrap;`! I had this issue with the ui-gridblocks from an ui-grids within other elements.

Comment: ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ ❤ <-- this cannot express my gratitude to you!